# Why I get: Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from a use of ‘/’?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in a *.hs* file

```
module TypeInference1 where
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x + y + 3
```

Then if I check the type of **f**, I obtain the following result, which is ok:

```
*TypeInference1> :t f
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

If I pass to **f** one parameter of type fractional and check its type I obtain:

```
*TypeInference1> :t f 1.0
f 1.0 :: Fractional a => a -> a
```

But on the other hand if I change the **f** by setting a division operation on one of its arguments, as follows:
`f x y = x/2 + y + 3`

I obtain the following error:

```
5-typeInference1.hs:4:9: error:
    • Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from a use of ‘/’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   f :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
        at 5-typeInference1.hs:3:1-25
      Possible fix:
        add (Fractional a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            f :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
    • In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘x / 2’
      In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘x / 2 + y’
      In the expression: x / 2 + y + 3
```

Why does this happen and why the type can not be deduced when I change the function **f** as above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**: by specifying `Num a => a -> a -> a` you claim that `f` can deal with *all* `a`s that are members of the `Num` typeclass, but the `(/)` can only work with types that are members of the `Fractional` typeclass.

[**`Fractional`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) is a "sub" typeclass of `Num`. That means that all types that are a member of `Fractional` are a member of `Num`, but this does *not* hold vice versa.

By specifying as type for f:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

You say that `f` can deal with *all* types `a` that are members of the `Num` typeclass. But that is incorrect if you define `f` as `f x y = x/2 + y + 3`, since `x/2` means that `x` should be a type that is a member of `Fractional`. Indeed `(/)` has type [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-). You thus should make `f` more restrictive, such that you can only pass values that are of type `a` with `a` a member of the `Fractional` typeclass:

```
f :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x/2 + y + 3
```

Comment: Can you also explain why for the case *TypeInference1> :t f 1.0 we obtain: f 1.0 :: Fractional a => a -> a;  despite function f has been declared as f :: Num a => a -> a -> a ? I understand what you explained, but this aspect still keeps me confused.

Comment: Becuase `Fractional` is a subtype of `Num`, so that works. It thus derives that your parameter `1.0 :: Fractional b => b` is the same as `a` in `Num a => a -> a -> a` and therefore that thus the type of the result is `(Fractional a, Num a) => a -> a` or more simpler `Fractional a => a -> a`. Therefore `f 1.0` can only work for all types that are `Fractional`.

Comment: The basic principle with polymorphic types is that the caller of the function gets to choose what type to supply, within the constraints given in the function's type. Your original `f` can work on any numeric type, and all its arguments must be of the same type. When it is supplied with `1.0`, which can be any Fractional type, this is fine, and leads to the `Fractional` constraint, since all `a`s in `f`'s definition are the same. But your second `f`, by using the `/` operator, can suddenly no longer work on all numeric types. Your type signature says it can, and this is why GHC rejects it.

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed explanations. Now I understood.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have in mind this **kind of** typeclass hierarchy:

```
             Num a
             /   \  
            /     \ 
           /       \
  (Fractional a)  (Integral a)
      /   \           /   \  
     /     \         /     \ 
    /       \       /       \
 Double   Float   Integer   Int
```

Now if you say:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

You are telling that all the **functions** that will be used by `a` will be from the `Num` typeclass, these here:

```
(+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-))
```

If you check the body of your function:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x/2 + y + 3
```

you are using `(/)` function, and that function belongs to the "sub" typeclass of `Num`, `Fractional` and `Fractional` has these functions allowed:

```
fromRational, (recip | (/))
```

> Conclusion:

If you use one **function** that belongs from one o the bottom in the hierarchy, you are restricting the type to that level.

> Fix

The good thing is, if you read carefully the stack error, in some part of it says:

```
  Possible fix:
    add (Fractional a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
```

And let's try it:

```
f :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x/2 + y + 3
```